# Setting Image properties in XAML template

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, xaml

So I have a template for a button with an image and a textblock. The images I have are too large, and I'd like to scale them down.

```
<Style x:Key="ImageButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=(local:ButtonProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"></ContentPresenter>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Is the specific block of code I have. However, when I try to add `Height="X"` to the template, I get errors. Is there a way to specify the image size within the template itself?

Comment: Try to use Grid with 2 rows instead of StackPanel

Comment: Will that allow me to use `Height=X` within Image?

Comment: Are you assigning string to Height like Height="20" or trying to assign integer value? Also it would be helpful, if you can post the errors you got.

Comment: I just want a way to set the image size to a predetermined value

Comment: `<Image Source="{Binding Path=(local:ButtonProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Height="40" Width="40" />`

Comment: i just tried it (copy pasted your template) and I can set the height on the image without any errors

Comment: @dvvrd I swear I tried that and it didn't work before. Oh well, it works now! If you want to post that as an answer, you have my gratitude :)

Comment: @Parker: No, thanks a lot:) That was too easy. And if I will do it this question will bubble to the top of list and everyove will downvote you ;)

Comment: Haha good point, I am embarrassed about how I didn't get this working before -_-. Thanks again! =)